# Wordpress Loop: Insert Content After Specific Post Number

Tags: wordpress, post, loops, count

I am wondering if there is a way to insert a block of content after a specific post number in my Custom Post Loop.

Essentially, I want to say:

After the 2 most recent mosts, insert this block of code.

If that can be done, I would also be interested in knowing if something like this is achievable:

Start a Custom Post Loop that excludes a specific Post Format (or Category), but after every 2 posts, insert 1 of the excluded Post Formats.

Thanks for any assistance.

```
    <!-- #STICKY-POSTS |begin| -->
    <section id="sticky-posts">

    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'cat' => '8' );
        $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args);
        while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();

            get_template_part('format', 'standard');

        endwhile;
    ?>
```

Comment: In the editor section you can add to the php script that renders posts pretty easily.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. I do not know how exactly to write the PHP to pull off what I am asking. Opening up the editor kind of goes without saying. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: If you'll post that section I'll take a look at it, I don't have the code to pull up for your specific theme.

Comment: K, I added the link to the original post. You will see that we a #STICKY-POSTS section that contains a loop of 2 posts, then a #MAIN-FEATURES section which contains a loop of 1 post, and then a #PORTFOLIO-POSTS section that contains the rest of our posts. I would love to make this a single loop, and basically say "take this category and put it at the top, place a block of code beneath that category before adding a post from this other category, and then go ahead and pull in all the other posts." You help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your block of content its own template file?

Comment: Oh sorry, the block of content I am trying to insert is the #we-design <article> found within #MAIN-CONTENT. Whatever method makes most sense for pulling this off, I am open to. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure how wordpress renders that page, are you needing that included in the example or do you just need the logic?

Comment: Basically, if I could be given the logic to know how to count posts and execute something after a certain number of posts, I think I could probably manage the rest. I did a lot of digging on Google and found hints towards this functionality, but no examples as to how to actually do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<!-- #STICKY-POSTS |begin| -->
<section id="sticky-posts">

<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'cat' => '8' );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args);
    $x = 0;
    while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
        if($x==2) {
        display your thing here.
        $x=0;
        }
        get_template_part('format', 'standard');
        $x++
    endwhile;
?>
```

Unless I botched something, x=0 will turn 1 at first normal post, 2 at second normal post then return true on the if statement, got back to 0 and rinse repeat.

Comment: Unfortunately that appears to simply break the page. I tried removing everything from the template and placed just that bit of code and still a blank page. Also, I added a '$' infront of the X variable to troubleshoot and it made no difference. To bad, I had a good feeling about that code :(

Comment: This won't exactly work now that I think about it anyways, it will ski p every third post when it displays your block.

Comment: The new edit should work just fine though. Try telling it to echo some random text where it should be displaying your custom block, see if it puts out anything.

Comment: Awesome! You forgot a ; after the $x++ but that code works to spit out a chuck of code after every 2nd post. Good stuff dude! I will take some time to work on this and see how much I can tweak it. I appreciate the time and effort you put in on this. Once I get things in order, I will update my original post with the results. Thanks again.